# TextView custom subclass - textViewDidChange does not trigger

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm trying to add an variable to my TextView subclass but I can't get textViewDidChange to work properly once I do that and I think it's because the delegate.

It works without the subclass and prints the itemOrderID. How can I get this to work with my custom subclass?

```
class textViewSub: UITextView {
    var itemOrderID: Double = 0.0
}

class TextviewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: textViewSub!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: textViewSub) {
        let id = textView.tag
        let text = textView.text
        let itemOrderID = textView.itemOrderID

        print(itemOrderID)
    }
}
```

cellForRowAt code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextviewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextviewCell
   cell.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.textView.itemOrderID = checklistData[indexPath.section].checklistItems?[indexPath.row].itemOrderID ?? 0.0
   cell.textView.delegate = cell

   return cell
}
```

Comment: Make sure you set `textView` to be a `TextViewSub` in IB as well. Also, class names should be capitalized.

Comment: @Koen Yes its already set

Comment: please make sure, that awakeFromNib is really called every time the cell is reused. Or to be sure, put textView.delegate = self better in cellForRowAtIndexPath to make sure, the delegate is really set always.

Comment: @Chris it crashes now when I have cell.textView.delegate = self as! UITextViewDelegate in the cellForRowAt

Comment: please show us your cellForRow ...code.

Comment: ah, ok, you should do it this way: cell.textView.delegate = cell ...because this is your delegate, not the tableview

Comment: Ok did not crash but still same result - does not print itemOrderID on textViewDidChange

Comment: but still wrong: cell.textView.delegate = self as! UITextViewDelegate (or didn't you update it here?)

Comment: Forgot to change it here before I updated post.  Same result.

Comment: but you change the text via input, not via coding, right?

Comment: Yes in the simulator (or device) when text is inputted into the textView it should print(itemOrderID) every keystroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `textViewDidChange` function does not match the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.
It should be:

```
 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
      guard let sub = textView as? textViewSub else { return }
      let id = sub.tag
      let text = sub.text
      let itemOrderID = sub.itemOrderID

      print(itemOrderID)
  }
```